# How to restrict aceess to route which is common for 5 roles in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5, routes, roles, laravel-permission

In laravel I have declared five different roles like admin,client,employee. I need to restrict user from accessing url based on their roles.

Comment: declared route like this Route::get('users/{id}/{role}/{path}', ['as' => 'users.showRoleBaseUsers', 'uses' => 'UserController@showRoleBaseUsers']);  now need to restrict it based on roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create middleware (https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#defining-middleware) if roles access then `return $next($request);` otherwise `return redirect('home');`

Comment: I have tried this and it helps me.Thank you.